# How to move the first node to the end of the list in linked list c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I want to take the first node of my linked list to the end of it,
but so far i couldn't.

the idea that i had is to create a new node that contains the first node's info and then delete the first node, and then add the new node to the end of the list.

this is my code, but it doesn't work because i can't access the start pointer in my list since it's private:

```
Newnode-> = list.start->next->info;
list.RemoveFront();     //a function to remove the first node.
list.AddBack(Newnode);  //a function to add the element to the end of the list.
```

Comment: can you show compiler error. and more code

Comment: Well, `Newnode-> = ...` is already invalid syntax. Doesn't your list class or the list's node class have a method for getting the front node's value? Your plan for pulling that data, dropping the front node, then adding a back node certainly seems doable (assuming said-data is properly copyable and, if needed, follows the [RO3 idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). But you need the node data to make that a reality. A list method that just relocates the node itself would obviously work too (and avoid the copy in the process).

Comment: @WhozCraig that's my issue actually.. i can't access the data of the first node, can you please help me find a way to access it.

Comment: Pardon the obvious question, what possible good is a linked list who's node data cannot be accessed?

Comment: @WhozCraig because my linked list class is  created in a different file. i'm trying to use encapsulation. i'm still new in data-structures so i hope you can help me with a way to do that.

Comment: Your list should have methods for most of this. Getting the front node data, the back node data, some N'th node data, popping the front, the back, some N'th, etc. It sounds like you simply haven't provided the needed functionality for what you want to do as a public interface to your list. Perhaps do that.

Comment: @WhozCraig i know that, but i don't know how to return the info of the first node, especially that the info is an object's data not just of primitive type(int or double)

Comment: You really need to review you data structures reference material.  Maybe throw your present reference in the trash and purchase a book that **you** can actually understand.

Answer (score 1):

Are you serious?

There are two cases:

1. Your linked list has a pointer to the last link *(Very useful)*
2. Or you don't.

If you don't have a pointer to the last node, traverse the list and create one.

Here are the operations:

1. Temp points to first node.
2. Change Head to point to 2nd Node.
3. Set the Temp node to point to nil or null.
4. Make the last node point to the temp node.
5. Make the Tail pointer point to the temp node.

Please draw this out.  Linked lists are always easier to understand when you draw them.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation; However, what i want is just to know how to point to the first node so that i can do all the other steps

Comment: That is what I don't understand.  In my understanding of a linked list implementation, there is always a pointer to the first or head node.  Maybe you have a doubly linked list and point in the middle.  How is your list working if you don't have some kind of pointer to the first node?